# Cannot instantiate chaincode on hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I tried instantiating well tested chaincode onto my fabric network but got issue summarized as "cannot register chaincode".
There is no trace of chaincode container. I have tested my chaincodes and they pass all the base tests so there is no issue with the code. No matter on whichever orgs peer I run this, instantiation keeps failing.

Can someone help?

Hyperledger fabric version controlling platform mentions a same bug filed but I don't see what solution they came up with (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-14638). They seem to say something about the node version mismatch.

cli logs :

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.flightcommand.com:7050 -C flightcommandchannel -l node -n TripCC -v v0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P 'AND ("CapitalcityMSP.member")' 2019-05-08 05:40:55.146 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc 2019-05-08 05:40:55.150 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0**
```

peer logs :

```
[flightcommandchannel][97cbe635] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc" (98834ms) 
2019-05-08 05:42:33.897 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 18f [flightcommandchannel][97cbe635] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 0 
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1 /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63 runtime.goexit /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 chaincode registration failed
2019-05-08 05:42:33.898 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 190 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=192.168.96.12:38100 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1m38.836283s
```

Comment: What version of Fabric are you using?  and what version of fabric-contract-api (or fabric-shim)?

Comment: I use fabric-shim: 1.4.0 and fabric images with "latest" tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 7052 is unlikely to be the problem here.  This is the explanation (from core.yaml) about port 7052.

```
# The endpoint this peer uses to listen for inbound chaincode connections.
# If this is commented-out, the listen address is selected to be
# the peer's address (see below) with port 7052
# chaincodeListenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7052
```

In your debug output I see `"chaincodeBuildlevel":"1.4.1-rc1"`

I think you are using Fabric Images for 1.4.1-rc1.

I would suggest removing the Docker Images on your system and replacing with 1.4.1 and then using fabric-shim 1.4.1 too for consistency.  This might clear the problem, but will certainly be a better place to continue investigations.

**Updated following comments**

With Docker Compose, if your group of containers are started on the same Network Bridge (on the same host machine/VM) they can resolve each others' addresses and connect on any port.

The mapping of Ports in the `docker-compose.yaml` file maps ports from the host computer into the container (not between containers).

Port 7053 used to be used for Events in older versions of Fabric, but it is not used in 1.4.1

The error you have now shown in the comment is a Name Resolution error so not to do with the ports.  Perhaps your containers are not on the same Docker Bridge?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still confused. In the docker-compose.yaml file, I have only specified mapping for ports 7051 and 7053 for the peer. How can the chaincode which also runs as a container be able to connect to the peer on 7052 without the proper mappings. I would also like to know how can I specify chaincodeListenAddress in the docker-compose env variable to override 7052.Also I seek knowledge on what is 7053 port being used for.

Comment: Please read my answer above. I have edited it and added core.yaml's content.

Comment: I changed my fabric images version to 1.4.1. Still the same issue arises.
"Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failure\n is something that tells the peer address NODE_ENV=development node account.js "--peer.address" "peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com:7052" is wrong and unreachable

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the issue. I missed out a ENV Variable to specify in the peer docker-compose.yaml.

"**- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=network_1.0**"

Where network_1.0 is the name of the docker network. Although the error messages was not so descriptive, I took some pain and rebuilt my prevoius project where chaincode deployment did work and compared it with my current project. Found only this piece missing and after adding it, to my surprise, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the logging level of the peer and got to see something bizzare. Following are the chaincode logs in debug mode.

```
2019-05-08 11:21:52.980 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 04f [flightcommandchannel][d01daf8c] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
2019-05-08 11:21:54.424 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 050
2019-05-08 11:21:54.426 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 051 > trip@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
2019-05-08 11:21:54.427 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 052 > **NODE_ENV=development node account.js "--peer.address" "peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com:7052"**
2019-05-08 11:21:54.428 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 053
2019-05-08 11:21:55.124 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 054 2019-05-08T11:21:55.118Z debug [lib/chaincode.js]                                 debug: Starting chaincode using options {"_":[],"peer.address":"peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com:7052","chaincodeBuildlevel":"1.4.1-rc1","chaincodeLoggingLevel":"debug","chaincodeLoggingFormat":"%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}","chaincodeIdName":"AccountChaincode:v0","chaincodeLoggingShim":"debug","peerTlsEnabled":"false","grpc.max_send_message_length":-1,"grpc.max_receive_message_length":-1,"grpc.keepalive_time_ms":110000,"grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms":110000,"grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms":20000,"grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data":0,"grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls":1,"module-path":"/usr/local/src","modulePath":"/usr/local/src","chaincode-id-name":"AccountChaincode:v0","timestamp":"2019-05-08T11:21:55.118Z"}
2019-05-08 11:21:55.128 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 055 2019-05-08T11:21:55.127Z debug [lib/chaincode.js]                                 debug: Peer URL {"0":"g","1":"r","2":"p","3":"c","4":":","5":"/","6":"/","7":"p","8":"e","9":"e","10":"r","11":"0","12":".","13":"o","14":"n","15":"e","16":"s","17":"k","18":"y","19":".","20":"f","21":"l","22":"i","23":"g","24":"h","25":"t","26":"c","27":"o","28":"m","29":"m","30":"a","31":"n","32":"d","33":".","34":"c","35":"o","36":"m","37":":","38":"7","39":"0","40":"5","41":"2","timestamp":"2019-05-08T11:21:55.127Z"}
2019-05-08 11:21:55.135 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 056 2019-05-08T11:21:55.135Z info [lib/chaincode.js]                                  info: Registering with peer peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com:7052 as chaincode "AccountChaincode:v0" {"timestamp":"2019-05-08T11:21:55.135Z"}
2019-05-08 11:21:55.147 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 057 2019-05-08T11:21:55.146Z debug [lib/handler.js]                                   debug: Sending chat message: {"type":1,"payload":{"type":"Buffer","data":[18,19,65,99,99,111,117,110,116,67,104,97,105,110,99,111,100,101,58,118,48]}} {"timestamp":"2019-05-08T11:21:55.146Z"}
2019-05-08 11:21:55.440 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0] func2 -> INFO 058 2019-05-08T11:21:55.437Z error [lib/handler.js]                                   error: Chat stream with peer - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failure\n    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)\n    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:26)\n    at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1306:15)\n    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)\n    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)\n    at /usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1123:18" {"timestamp":"2019-05-08T11:21:55.437Z"}
2019-05-08 11:21:55.617 UTC [dockercontroller] func2 -> INFO 059 Container dev-peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com-AccountChaincode-v0 has closed its IO channel
2019-05-08 11:21:56.091 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 05a [flightcommandchannel][d01daf8c] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (3111ms)
2019-05-08 11:21:56.091 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 05b [flightcommandchannel][d01daf8c] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed
2019-05-08 11:21:56.091 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05c unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.25.0.4:59932 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.1157286s
```

So here lies the problem. My peer listens on port 7051, not 7052. Ideally the command should look like "NODE_ENV=development node account.js "--peer.address" "peer0.onesky.flightcommand.com:7051"". I have no idea from where it is getting 7052.

P.S.
I added following to get a better overview of the issue in the chaincode instantiation.

- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
- CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=debug
- CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug

core.yaml says

```
# The endpoint this peer uses to listen for inbound chaincode connections.
# If this is commented-out, the listen address is selected to be
# the peer's address (see below) with port 7052
# chaincodeListenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7052

# The endpoint the chaincode for this peer uses to connect to the peer.
# If this is not specified, the chaincodeListenAddress address is selected.
# And if chaincodeListenAddress is not specified, address is selected from
# peer listenAddress.
# chaincodeAddress: 0.0.0.0:7052
```

So I concluded since both are commented, 7051 is used as the address to listen to chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem whenever I tried to instantiate the chaincode, I got this error

peer logs:

```
2019-05-09 04:05:38.285 EDT [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 15c [mychannel][03349c15] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
/home/alex/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337
chaincode registration failed
```

I was able to fix it by changing `build.gradle` file, make sure in your `build.gradle` you have set `Main-Class` in `manifest attributes` to your main java file.

```
shadowJar {
    baseName = 'chaincode'
    version = null
    classifier = null

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.XXX'
    }
}
```

Where `XXX` is the `XXX.java` file where your `main()` function is defined

Not sure how can this be done in node. But I hope this will give you the idea.

Comment: where can I find this file build.gradle. Is it specific to Fabric or Java?

Comment: `build.gralde` can be found in your java gradle project, in projects root directory.

Comment: OP is using node, while this answer is specific to java.

Comment: The question is tagged Hyperledger Fabric not only specific to node.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue not find any solution yet.

```
2021-03-25 04:53:55.840 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 046 failed to invoke chaincode bankcc, error: container exited with 0
```

github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:118

**and this my chaincode container logs**

```
Error starting Marbles02 chaincode: ccid must be specified
```

**but i specified the ccid here**

```
server := &shim.ChaincodeServer{
    //CCID: ccid,
    CCID:    os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_CCID"),
    Address: os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_ADDRESS"),
    CC:      chaincode,
    TLSProps: shim.TLSProperties{
        Disabled: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,and I have sloved it by change peer env,and I think this problem was caused by **CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT**,actual,I dont know why .

I set CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true ,commented CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS and CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS,It is work.

my peer env like this :

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
#CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:30012
#CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30012
```